# Pandas not perform calculations other than sum. TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling, mean

```
d = [[1, 3], [1, 3], [4, 6], [3, 6], [3, 3], [8, 3], [3, 7]]

test = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

[image: Show dataframe]

```
test.info()
```

[image]

```
test.sum()
```

[image]

I only do the sum function. When I call other functions, it gives me the error:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`.

```
test.describe()
test.mean()
test.max()
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-6f207d50b4e2> in <module>
----> 1 test.describe()

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in describe(self, percentiles, include, exclude, datetime_is_numeric)
  10093             data = self.select_dtypes(include=include, exclude=exclude)
  10094 
> 10095         ldesc = [describe_1d(s) for _, s in data.items()]
  10096         # set a convenient order for rows
  10097         names: List[Label] = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in <listcomp>(.0)
  10093             data = self.select_dtypes(include=include, exclude=exclude)
  10094 
> 10095         ldesc = [describe_1d(s) for _, s in data.items()]
  10096         # set a convenient order for rows
  10097         names: List[Label] = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in describe_1d(data)
  10067                 return describe_categorical_1d(data)
  10068             elif is_numeric_dtype(data):
> 10069                 return describe_numeric_1d(data)
  10070             elif is_datetime64_any_dtype(data.dtype) and datetime_is_numeric:
  10071                 return describe_timestamp_1d(data)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in describe_numeric_1d(series)
   9998             )
   9999             d = (
> 10000                 [series.count(), series.mean(), series.std(), series.min()]
  10001                 + series.quantile(percentiles).tolist()
  10002                 + [series.max()]

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in stat_func(self, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  11463         if level is not None:
  11464             return self._agg_by_level(name, axis=axis, level=level, skipna=skipna)
> 11465         return self._reduce(
  11466             func, name=name, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, numeric_only=numeric_only
  11467         )

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _reduce(self, op, name, axis, skipna, numeric_only, filter_type, **kwds)
   4234                 )
   4235             with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 4236                 return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
   4237 
   4238     def _reindex_indexer(self, new_index, indexer, copy):

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py in _f(*args, **kwargs)
     69             try:
     70                 with np.errstate(invalid="ignore"):
---> 71                     return f(*args, **kwargs)
     72             except ValueError as e:
     73                 # we want to transform an object array

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py in f(values, axis, skipna, **kwds)
    118                     #  TypeError if called
    119                     kwds.pop("mask", None)
--> 120                     result = bn_func(values, axis=axis, **kwds)
    121 
    122                     # prefer to treat inf/-inf as NA, but must compute the func

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: I tried the numbers / code you provided and it works for me. Is it possible that `test` dataframe is not defined anymore when you try to get `test.mean()` etc?

Comment: The stacktrace shows it fails on `data.describe()`, not `test.describe()`. What is inside `data`?

Comment: @Marat: sorry I fixed the code. I know this question sounds so basic and even "stupid". I don't have such error before. It happened today and I don't know why :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. This code works just fine with this data

Comment: @tania: I'm sure I used the `test` dataframe and it exists when I call `test.mean()` and `test.describe()`